# ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor in 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

I have tried via tnsname.ora file. 
If you have any other alternative please ping me?

Comment: Why there's MySql tag?

Comment: This a very common problem. Please look at the right handside part of this page, titled `Related`, you could see lots of samples, one of which would be able to work for you I think.

Comment: The error is telling you that you found the listener running on the specified server, but the listener didn't recognise the service name you provided. Are you sure that service is really available on that server?